# How to add two time values together in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with `'accumulate_low_risk'` and `'accumulate_high_risk'`. Both are `timedata (time(7))` in the format `00:00:00.0000000`.

I want to add them together and place them into another timedata called 'combined_shift_total'

I have tried to convert them to seconds, add the results together and convert them back to timedata but i'm getting lost.

The table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE accumulate_time ('id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,time DATETIME NOT NULL,worker_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES worker_table(worker_id),shift_start DATETIME NOT NULL,accumulate_low_risk TIME NOT NULL,accumulate_high_risk TIME NOT NULL,combined_shift_total TIME NOT NULL)
```

I was trying something along the lines of....

```
select Sum(Left (CONVERT(nvarchar(30),accumulate_low_risk, 126),2) * 3600 + substring(accumulate_low_risk, 4,2) * 60 + substring(accumulate_low_risk, 7,2))
from accumulate_time WHERE id IN (SELECT max(id) FROM accumulate_time WHERE worker_id = 6)
```

But this is way too messy.

My knowledge of SQL is limited so I'm sure there's a simple way to achieve this.

I would be very grateful for any and all help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like SQL Server. You can achieve it by counting how many seconds you have in your columns using `datediff()` and then add it to `00:00:00.0000000` using `dateadd()`. Please note that I don't know how precise is your data, so if you want it to me more precise you need to i.e. change `second` to `milisecond`. It's shift data so it shouldn't excess 24 hours, but please note what in this case it wouldn't work.

```
select cast(dateadd(second, datediff(second, '00:00:00.0000000', accumulate_low_risk) + datediff(second, '00:00:00.0000000', accumulate_high_risk), '2019-01-01') as time(7))
from accumulate_time
```

An examply how it works on a temp table:

```
create table #time (t1 time(7), t2 time(7))
insert into #time values ('01:12:04.0000000','00:12:04.0000000')

select cast(dateadd(second, datediff(second, '00:00:00.0000000', t1) + datediff(second, '00:00:00.0000000', t2), '2019-01-01') as time(7))
from #time
```